# Migrating services to Spring Boot 3 - Unable to convert javax.xml.namespace to jakarta.xml.namespace

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jakarta-migration

We are migrating our services to Spring Boot 3. However, we have encountered an issue regarding the conversion from `javax.xml.namespace` to `jakarta.xml.namespace`. It seems that this namespace has not been migrated to Jakarta EE yet. As a result, our application is failing to start up with Tomcat 10.

Could anyone please suggest a workaround or solution for this issue? We are seeking a way to successfully convert the `javax.xml.namespace` references to the corresponding `jakarta.xml.namespace` ones, ensuring compatibility with Spring Boot 3 and Tomcat 10.

Comment: Which dependency does `javax.xml.namespace` come from? I think that `javax.xml.namespace` should stay starting with `javax`. See also [this issue](https://github.com/apache/tomcat-jakartaee-migration/issues/9).

Answer (score 3):

javax -> jakarta is only for JavaEE (JakartaEE). Some javax.* packages are of SE, not EE, for example:

```
javax.sql.*
javax.xml.*
javax.naming.*
javax.swing.*
```

They will simply keep javax.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is more complicated. The Jigsaw project *has* moved subpackages from `javax.xml`: so `javax.xml.soap` ended up in `jakarta.xml.soap-api`) and `javax.xml.ws` in `jakarta.xml.ws-api`.

Only just `javax.xml.` **`namespace`** was **not** touched.

Answer (score 0):

As @Will Phi already wrote, the Jigsaw project did not move *all* `javax` packages to `jakarta(EE)`.

For example, from `javax.xml` only 3 sub-packages [have been moved](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/):

- `javax.xml.bind` (→ `jakarta.xml.bind-api`)
- `javax.xml.soap` (→ `jakarta.xml.soap-api`)
- `javax.xml.ws` (→ `jakarta.xml.ws-api`)

Other `javax.xml.` sub-packages (just as `.namespace`, `.datatype`, `.parsers`, `.transform`, `.validation` and `.xpath` - see [java.xml packages summary](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/module-summary.html#packages-summary) for complete list) *remained* at `javax`.